# Identify library file/Source that contains native method implementation

Tags: java, implementation, native, native-code

How to identify library file that contains implementation of native methods ?

Ex.

```
public native String intern();
```

Where can I find implementation `(source code)` of `String.intern()` method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer for `String.intern()` with quick [google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3aopenjdk.java.net%20inurl%3acpp.html%20intern)

- [constant pool](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~andrew/6781583/webrev.01/src/share/vm/oops/constantPoolOop.cpp.html)
- [symbol table cpp](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~jcoomes/completed/2011/6962931-intern-post/src/share/vm/classfile/symbolTable.cpp.html) : [symbol table  hpp](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~coleenp/6990754_3/src/share/vm/classfile/symbolTable.hpp.html)

> *Yet to find answer for generic way to identify native implementation/library*

Answer (score 0):

Download this JDK 6 library:

http://download.java.net/jdk6/source/

and search through sources.

But I think, some code implementations are not accessible as OpenSource

Answer (score 0):

There is no *general* approach to find source code for (any) native method. But if we narrow the question to the *native jre methods*, then you can find some implementations in the (full) source code of [openJdk](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/).

Just keep in mind that those are the implementations for just one JRE, other implementations of Java may have different implementations of the native methods.

To find the source for a native method: search the repository for the JNI header files, then you should get the name of the C/C++ function that provides the implementation.