# String initialising in Java

Tags: java, string

Considering the code below:

1. How is the `str1` object created without using `new String()`?
2. Why do the `str1` and `str2` objects refer to same memory location?

```
String str1 = "hello";
String str2 = "hello";
```

Comment: How do you know `str1` and `str2` point to the same memory location? Did you test this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is all described in the java language specification.

See [3.10.5 String Literals](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.5):

> Each string literal is a reference (§4.3) to an instance (§4.3.1,
>   §12.5) of class String (§4.3.3). String objects have a constant value.
>   String literals-or, more generally, strings that are the values of
>   constant expressions (§15.28)-are "interned" so as to share unique
>   instances, using the method String.intern.

Answer (score 3):

In java you can create String objects without calling the new operator.So, `String str1 = "hello"` is equivalent to `String str1 = new String("hello")`. It is done like this, to make the string declaration similar to the primitive data types.

regarding why are they referring to same memory location:

> In java there is a concept of [String literal pool](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-string-literal-pool/3).To cut down the number of String objects created in the JVM, the String class keeps a pool of strings. Each time your code create a string literal, the JVM checks the string literal pool first. If the string already exists in the pool, a reference to the pooled instance returns. If the string does not exist in the pool, a new String object instantiates, then is placed in the pool.

```
 String str1 = "Hello";  
 String str2 = "Hello"; 
 System.out.print(str1 == str2);
```

Prints `True`.

If you do :

```
String str1 = "Hello";  
String str2 = new String("Hello");
System.out.print(str1 == str2);
```

Prints `False`.

because, String object is created out of the String literal pool.

Answer (score 1):

"hello" is a string literal in Java. Java creates a pool of string literals because strings are **immutable and reusable**. By `new String("hello")` you will be creating an extra string object even though the equivalent literal already exists in the pool.

Answer (score 0):

As the [string javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) suggests

```
String str1 = "hello";
```

is equivalent to

```
char data[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
String str = new String(data);
```

And As [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html#229744) suggests Constant strings (in this case `"hello"`) are  [String.intern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29)ed  meaning they share same memory and refer to same reference. All interend strings are stored in a String constant pool (see this post for details [Identify library file/Source that contains native method implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662214/identify-library-file-source-that-contains-native-method-implementation))

> strings that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28)-are
>   "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method

However if you do create it with `new String()` yourself, new memory will be allocated

```
String str  = "hello";
String str1 = new String(str);
String str2 = new String(str);
assert: str1 != str2;
//Force strings into constant pool
String str3 = str1.intern();
String str4 = str2.intern();
assert: str == str3;
assert: str3 == str4;
```