# Native implementation of Process.waitFor method

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have used a method [waitFor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) of Process class, to execute some UNIX command. The command is executing successfully but it is returning `2`, that according to convention means [abnormal termination](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29).

I googled and [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015491/exit-value-from-java-lang-processwaitfor) that it depends on *"source code of the program that is outputting this exit code"*. So I tried to find the source code for waitFor method, I came to know that it is a native method and defined in `ProcessImpl` class.

```
public native int waitFor();
```

So I [searched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662214/identify-library-file-source-that-contains-native-method-implementation) for native implementation of this method from [here](http://download.java.net/jdk6/source/). But I did not found the file that provide me the native implementation of `waitFor` method.

**My question is** how to find the file in which native implementation of this method is written?

Comment: I'm not sure, but doesn't `waitFor` just return the exit code of the process?  In JDK7, `waitFor()` is written in Java (using `waitForInterruptibly` which is native), and `waitFor()` returns `exitValue()` which calls `getExitCodeProcess()` which really looks like it's just the exit code of the process.  So the process you're running did an `exit(2);` [if it's written in C] or something equivalent.  I don't think the native `waitFor` source in JDK6 is going to help you.

Comment: The source code of Process,waitFor() doesn't have anything to do with why the execute program exited with code 2. You're barking up the wrong tee.

Comment: thanks @ajb and EJP for replying, even though looking after the native implementation of `waitFor` method will not help me, still I wanted to know how to find in which **file** the native implementation of `waitFor` method is written, for time being I am least concerned about what waitFor returns, but yes I wanted to know the flow how that value is returned and from where it is returned.

Answer (score 4):

The `source code` mentioned refers to the source of the *program you are executing with your `Process` object*.

In your case, it is the UNIX command you are executing using the `Process` that is terminating with exit code 2, not the `waitFor()` method itself.

So to answer your actual question, the answer is: Within the source code of the JDK you are using, for example [here is the source for OpenJDK6](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/).

However, if your actual question is **"Why is waitFor() returning a non zero exit code"**, then the answer is: The Process you are executing with Java has returned a non zero exit code, and the `Process` object is informing you via the return of the `waitFor()` method

Comment: @Andreq Stubbs thanks for replying, my question was **how to find the file** in which native implementation of this method is written? I searched in `openjdk-6-src-b28-04_oct_2013.tar\jdk\src\share\native\java` directory but I did not found the `C` or `CPP` file that implements waitFor method, which is declared native in `ProcessImpl` class